# Sharing folder with 10m+ files on win xp takes hours to set access rights

Tags: windows, permissions, performance, share, directory

I try to share whole partition in windows xp. On this partition are 10+ milion files. Windows sets access rights to each of them and it has been doining that for last 12 hours and hasn't yet finished. Is there a quicker way to share folder with so many files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quickly changing Windows permissions for a huge directory tree?](http://serverfault.com/questions/51256/quickly-changing-windows-permissions-for-a-huge-directory-tree)

Comment: Lol.  I don't want to sound like too much of a prick, but like you said, Windows is applying a change to every single file on the partition, which is has more than 10 million files.  Yes, changing 10 million files is going to take a while.  Now that you've started, don't stop the process, or you run the risk of having incomplete NTFS security settings on your partition, which can cause some nasty problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only thing i can think of is to divide the files to number of folders. the number depends on the number of cores in your processor. then spawn a separate process of rights changing on each folder. This should take a little less time, although i must admit i do not see any in fact faster way to set permission then what you are already doing. This is just NTFS. Maybe this topic will guide you more: [Quickly changing Windows permissions for a huge directory tree?](https://serverfault.com/questions/51256/quickly-changing-windows-permissions-for-a-huge-directory-tree)